# Using Illuminate Database outside Laravel without PHP Artisan Commands

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-artisan, illuminate-container, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to set up database migrations using Illuminate's Database outside of a Laravel 4.2 project.  Everything I'm reading online indicated that it is completely doable to use any Illuminate components outside of Laravel, but the difficulty I'm having is creating the database migrations without using Artisan commands ("php artisan make:migration create_user_table").  If any one could help me out with this, I'd really appreciate it, because I know someone has had to find a solution to the problem before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use artisan commands you should include the package of it and configure your application accordingly.

`illuminate\database` package doesn't provide you and artisan commands to use.

Comment: My understanding is that artisan commands can only be used in a Laravel project, and the package isn't stand alone like the Illuminate components.  Is that correct?

Comment: No, you can still setup artisan for a non-laravel project but its way too much work. I personally use an another console package from 'awesome-php' repo in github.

Comment: I looked that up at https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#migrations and there are multiple packages listed.  it looks like this one might be best suited for what i'm trying to do? https://github.com/robmorgan/phinx

Comment: This is your choice, however you wish. ;)

Comment: It would be cool if you could up-vote and accept the answer if I could help.

Comment: I tried to upvote it but doesn't seem to be reflected.  It has a popup about me not having enough reputation.